# Не могу получить доступ к глобальной переменной в Python

Tags: python

```py
def myfunc():
    global x
    x = 11
print(x)
```

> ```
> x is not defined.
> ```

Почему? Это же глобальная переменная.

Comment: В ошибке говорится, что `x` не определена. Потому что вы её не определили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Python конструкция global X говорит, что эта переменная глобальная и описана она где-то во вне этой функции. Что-бы было понятно:

```
def myfunc():
    global x
    x = 11   
x=6
print(x)
myfunc()
print(x)
```

Результат:

```
 6
11
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы не вызвали функции, поэтому переменная не создалась. Добавьте вызов функции до вывода, и все заработает

```
def myfunc():
    global x
    x = 11

myfunc()
print(x)
```